# Nginx pass proxy to another nodejs server

Tags: node.js, nginx

Node js part:

```
app.listen(4000,"localhost");
```

---

Nginx default:

```
  server{
    server_name "mydomain";
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
    }
```

When i set it with localhost it's working.

When i run the node script on another server and set nginx configuration like this:

```
server{
    server_name "mydomain";
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.30:4000;
    }
    }
```

This is not working. I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway error when i try to connect "mydomain".

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with changing the node script.

`app.listen(4000,"localhost");` to `app.listen(4000);`